# Expo SecureStore getItem

Tags: react-native, expo, walkthrough

My code below won't run the if statement, only the else.

```
SecureStore.getItemAsync('notFirstLaunch').then((value) => {
      LaunchApp(value);
    });

    const LaunchApp = function (value) {
      console.log(value);
      if (value === "true") {
        return (
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 0 }} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#E65100' }}>
              <Main />
          </SafeAreaView>
        );
      }
      else {
        SecureStore.setItemAsync('notFirstLaunch', "true");
          return (
              <Walkthrough />
          ); 
      }
  };
```

my console.log returns value = true but my if statement never runs only the else, please help!

Comment: "true" would be considered as string. try by removing quotes.

Comment: it takes a string for key and value, taking out quote throw lots of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the code that is happening in the `.then` block. I can't put my finger on it but it seems to me that the return statements wouldn't affect the render.

This is how I would refactor your component if I was planning on doing what you are doing. Obviously you'll change what is returned for each use case rather than the simplistic views that I have put in.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notFirstLaunch: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.firstLaunchCheck();
  }

  firstLaunchCheck = () => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync('notFirstLaunch').then(value => {
      if (value !== 'true') {
        SecureStore.setItemAsync('notFirstLaunch', 'true');
      } 
      this.setState({notFirstLaunch: value === 'true'})
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.notFirstLaunch) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Main</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Walkthrough</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } 
  }
}
```

When the component mounts I call `firstLaunchCheck` it then updates the state of the notFirstLaunch variable if the value that has been stored in `SecureStore` equals "true" if it is the first launch it also sets the value in the `SecureStore`. The change in the state causes a re-render which then shows the correct view.

Comment: thank you for the workaround, you are correct about an issue with the code in the .then block. I will look more into it and update when I find a solution but your workaround has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the line in your file:
**import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';**

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because SecureStore just allows to store strings, and you are evaluating with Booleans, so the *if* statement always gets the *else* way. *Andrew*, on the other hand, are evaluating with 'true' and this is, in fact, a string.