# SecureStore using expo returns Promise instead of JWT token in reducer file

Tags: react-native, expo

So, I am trying to get JWT token *INITIAL_STATE* of my reducer.

I am using **'expo-secure-store'** package for store token using expo

But when i try to getToken it is returning me a promise instead of token value, like below:

```js
AuthUser: Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 1,
  "_W": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo3LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNocmVleWFjaEBzYXR2aXguY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJzaHJlZXlhY2hAc2F0dml4LmNvbSI",
  "_X": null,
}
```

Here is my code for retrieving token:

```js
import * as SecureStorage from 'expo-secure-store';

const _retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await SecureStorage.getItemAsync('token');
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const INIT_STATE = {
  loader: false,
  alertMessage: '',
  successMessage: '',
  showMessage: false,
  initURL: '',
  authUser: _retrieveData().then((token) => token),
  tempAuth: '',
  currentScreen: 0,
  showSuccessMessage: false,
  currentUser: null,
  sendOTP: false,
};
```

I have tried other **StackOverflow** solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63798588/5908465), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54189999/5908465) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66683270/5908465), but not able to get token as string value.

Answer (score 2):

In the export object change,

```js
authUser: _retrieveData().then(token => token),
```

to

```js
authUser: _retrieveData,
```

Now wherever you want to call this function, use it like this

```js
const response = await authUser();
console.log(response) 
// This will be the required token
```

**For Reference,**

Have a look at the storage object exported from [here](https://github.com/kartikeyvaish/EasyShop/blob/main/Frontend/auth/storage.js#L28)

You see, I passed a reference to the function here.

And used it [here](https://github.com/kartikeyvaish/EasyShop/blob/main/Frontend/App.js#L45) as mentioned above

Comment: @AndroidPlayer_Shree Happy to Help! If your issue is resolved consider accepting the answer as it may help users in the future. Thanks